# Laravel - Saving PDF into a BLOB, causing job serialization issues

Tags: laravel, jobs

I am storing a raw PDF into a binary/blob column in my database. This all works great in most cases.

I had an issue a while back with livewire where the blob was causing issues with rendering. This was easy to fix by adding the blob column to the models hidden array:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

I am now back here with a similar issue but no fix. When pushing one of these models into a job, the serializer fails due to not being able to encode this column.

The error we get is:

```sh
Unable to JSON encode payload. Error code: 5
```

My options/ideas so far:

- base64 encode the PDF and save into a text field.
- Maybe the new Laravel job encryption feature may help, but I am not on a version to be able to test this just yet.

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trait `SerializesModels` from your Job class or use an Eloquent model into constructor

From [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#class-structure)

> if your queued job accepts an Eloquent model in its constructor, only the identifier for the model will be serialized onto the queue. When the job is actually handled, the queue system will automatically re-retrieve the full model instance and its loaded relationships from the database. This approach to model serialization allows for much smaller job payloads to be sent to your queue driver.

Or dont use the whole model in the constructir but use the id directly.

Or simply save the PDF file to the filesystem and keep only its path in the database. Will ave you a lot of database read/write time + all the tinkering regarding big payloads